# remove leading and trailing quotes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, query, string-manipulation

I have a field that may start and end with quotes. I only want to remove the quotes if the string starts and ends with quotes. If quotes exists inside the string then I wish to retain them.

I have used `REVERSE` and stuff which works if the field does start and end with quotes but if it does not it just returns null.

How can I ensure I still get the field result if it did not start with quotes?

What I have:

```
REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(STUFF(fieldname, CHARINDEX('"', fieldname), LEN('"'), '')), CHARINDEX('"', REVERSE(STUFF(fieldname, CHARINDEX('"', fieldname), LEN('"'), '')), 1), 1, ''))
```

Comment: I only want to remove the quotes if the string starts and ends with quotes. If quotes exists inside the string then I wish to retain them.

Comment: What if a value _only starts_ or _only ends_ with a double quote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You could try something like this**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN RIGHT(fieldname,1) = '"' AND LEFT(fieldname,1) = '"' THEN REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(STUFF(fieldname, 1, 1, '')), 1, 1, '')) 
       WHEN RIGHT(fieldname,1) = '"' THEN REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(fieldname), 1, 1, '')) 
       WHEN LEFT(fieldname,1) = '"' THEN STUFF(fieldname, 1, 1, '')
       ELSE fieldname END as fieldname
FROM #temp;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cc2e3fa8f0742584e051589bcd142f17)

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT TRIM(' "' FROM fieldname) fieldname
FROM tablename
```

`TRIM()` function requires SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 4):

[Randi's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/244758/22336) works perfectly, and [Akina's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/244759/22336) is much tidier if you are on SQL Server 2017 or better, but on older versions you can do this with slightly less code and fewer operations like reverse/stuff. Given this data:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(col varchar(255));

INSERT #temp(col) 
  SELECT 'foo' UNION ALL SELECT '"bar"' 
  UNION ALL SELECT 'blat"' UNION ALL SELECT '"mort';
```

This query yields the same results:

```
SELECT col = SUBSTRING
(
  x,
  CASE s WHEN '"' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END,
  LEN(x) - CASE e WHEN '"' THEN 1 + CASE s WHEN '"' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE 0 END
)
FROM (SELECT x = col, s = LEFT(col,1), e = RIGHT(col,1) FROM #temp) y;
```

Results:

```
col
========
foo
bar
blat
mort
```

I'm assuming that a string *only* starting with a double quote or *only* ending with a double quote also needs that lone double quote removed.

Comment: A slight variation (but fundamentally the same approach): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=445fb070f3b115ed20d7afc0032e34ee&hide=3

Answer (score -2):

```
declare @str varchar(50)='"ajhd"lajhi"'

select case when (@str like '"%"') then substring(@str,2,len(@str)-2) else @str end as string
```

Comment: this does not work!!!!

Comment: `bla
"bla
bla"
bla
bla    
bla    "`